# Invalid object name when using Entity Framework to read SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to set up a database connection using Entity Framework in an ASP.NET Core application, but each time I attempt to read from my data context, it fails stating that the table I'm trying to get is invalid.

I'm relatively new to EF with ASP.NET Core, so I could be missing something obvious. How can I get EF to connect/find my object?

I have my connection string as follows:

```
Data Source=DbServer;Initial Catalog=AIT;Integrated Security=True
```

And the table that I'm trying to read from is on `DbServer`:

```
AIT.processing.orderProcessing
```

The error I'm getting when the DB context attempts to connect is this:

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'processing.orderProcessing'.

I've looked at the context itself when it runs, and it is connecting to the correct server. I've also validated that the database is correct in the connection string and that it contains the `processing.orderProcessing` table. I've also tried to explicitly tell EF that it should be connecting to a specific object by using the Table property on my c# class:

```
[Table("AIT.processing.orderProcessing")]
```

This just causes my error message to change to:

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'AIT.processing.orderProcessing'.

As far as I know, if it is connecting to `DBServer`, it should be able to find that table as it definitely exists, and it is spelled correctly. I just copy/pasted it from SSMS to make sure.

Edit: 
The below answer was what fixed it for me. Changing my Table attribute to this:

```
[Table("orderProcessing", Schema = "processing")]
```

Caused EF to be able to connect.

Comment: Probably account used for your app do not have privileges this table.

Comment: If you database is: AIT and your table name is: processing.orderProcessing than your mapping should be: [Table("processing.orderProcessing")].

Comment: I do have admin level permissions for the database I'm trying access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `AIT` is database name,`processing` is schema name and `orderProcessing` is the table name.

Try to set table name and scheme name separately using Data Annotations  like:

```
[Table("orderProcessing", Schema = "processing")]
```

Or in DbContext `OnModelCreating` using:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("orderProcessing", processing);
```

Comment: This worked, specifically setting the Schema as a separate property inside the Table property.

Answer (score 4):

If your database name is "AIT" and schema is "processing" you must express EF core your schema name.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.HasDefaultSchema("processing");
}
```

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I used `HasDefaultSchema("blopp")` and the tables are created like *blopp.Customers* etc. However, when I try to read from the tables by `Context.Customers.Count()`, I get the error that it't not there. Care to suggest a reason/solution? It's like `OnModelCreating` doesn't kick in when I use the context for operations (but is effective when creating migrations).

Comment: @KonradViltersten I called Count() function and it worked. How you named your table in EF ? 
private void ConfigureMyClass(EntityTypeBuilder<MyClass> builder)
 {
            builder.ToTable("MyClassTable");
}

Comment: I didn't call the table explicitly, so I assume that it was called as the class name is (pluralized, though). And when I set the default schema to *dbo* (or not set it explicitly at all), it works, so somehow, my classes during reading lose the set schema.

Comment: Afaik table names are pluralized versions as default. Is your problem solved by setting the table name explicitly?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd call it **solved** - it's more of an ugly hack. I'd rather understand why the specified default schema is used when migrating but not while reading from the DB. In my experience, such discrepancies are often a sign of something much worse not known yet but heading your way.   :)

Comment: In my experience, do not use EF migration. It just complicated software development.